# Error en tiempo de ejecucion JAVA

Tags: java

Hace poco habia mostrado un codigo que estaba fallando, al final pude resolvelro con los consejos de la comunidad y quiero agradecerles bastante, mas sin embargo tropiezo con un problema ahora, el programa tira el error mencionado en el titulo a la hora de compilar, cuando en el liceo no era asi... no se si sea problema del ordenador que tengo
ademas al desear ejecutarlo aparece lo siguiente

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1041)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:959)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:545)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:365)
at based1.<init>(based1.java:143)
at based1.main(based1.java:218)
```

el codigo se los muestro otra vez es

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

 public class based1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JTextField textfield1,textfield2,textfield3,textfield4,textfield5;
private JLabel label1,label2,label3,label4,label5;
private JButton boton1,boton2,boton3,boton4;
private JTextArea texto;

 //variables 
int id;
int aux1=0,aux2=0,aux3=0,aux4=0,aux5=0;
float aux6=0;

String linea="";
String linea1="";
String linea2="";
String linea3="";
String linea4="";
String linea5="";

public void limpiar(){
textfield1.setText("");
textfield2.setText("");
textfield3.setText("");
textfield4.setText("");
textfield5.setText("");

}

public void tabla1() {
Vector nombresColumnas=new Vector();
nombresColumnas.add("MATRICULA");
nombresColumnas.add("NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS");
nombresColumnas.add("EX1");
nombresColumnas.add("EX2");
nombresColumnas.add("EX3");
DefaultTableModel modelo=new DefaultTableModel(nombresColumnas,0);//0
JTable tabla=new JTable();
tabla.setModel(modelo);

try{ Class.forName ("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1){
System.out.println(e1.getMessage());}

try{
String password ="";
//nombre de la base de datos Acces con extencion *.mdb o *.accdb
String dbName = "curso1.mdb";
//direccion de la base de datos
String bd= System.getProperty ("user.dir") + "\\" + dbName + ";PWD=" + password;
Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);DBQ="+bd);
Statement estatuto = conexion.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = estatuto.executeQuery ("select * FROM lista ORDER BY MATRICULA"   );
while (rs.next())

   { 
Vector v;
v= new Vector();
v.add (rs.getString("MATRICULA"));
v.add (rs.getString("NOMBRE"));
v.add (rs.getInt("EX1"));
v.add (rs.getInt("EX2"));
v.add (rs.getInt("EX3"));
modelo.addRow(v);
}

///WHILE
JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane (tabla);
this.getContentPane().add (scroll);
scroll.setBounds(350,30,400,300);
scroll.setViewportView(tabla);
scroll.setVisible(true);
estatuto.close();
    conexion.close();
    }catch(SQLException e1) {System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                          }
this.setTitle("Datos Ingresados Correctamente!!!") ;
}

        public based1() {
             setLayout(null);

        label1=new JLabel("Matricula:");
        label1.setBounds(5,5,100,30);
        add(label1);
        textfield1=new JTextField();
        textfield1.setBounds(65,10,100,20);
        add(textfield1);

        label2=new JLabel("Nombres:");
        label2.setBounds(5,25,100,30);
        add(label2);

        textfield2=new JTextField();
        textfield2.setBounds(65,32,200,21);
        add(textfield2);

        label3=new JLabel("Nota 1:");
        label3.setBounds(5,53,100,30);
        add(label3);
        textfield3=new JTextField();
       textfield3.setBounds(65,55,50,21);
        add(textfield3);

        label4=new JLabel("Nota 2:");
        label4.setBounds(120,53,100,30);
         add(label4);
        textfield4=new JTextField();
        textfield4.setBounds(170,55,50,21);
        add(textfield4);

        label5=new JLabel("Nota 3:");
        label5.setBounds(225,53,100,30);
        add(label5);
        textfield5=new JTextField();
        textfield5.setBounds(280,55,50,21);
        add(textfield5);

        boton1=new JButton("Grabar");
        boton1.setMnemonic('G');
        boton1.setBounds(10,120,100,30);
        add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

        boton2=new JButton("Salir");
        boton2.setMnemonic('S');
        boton2.setBounds(220,120,100,30);
        add(boton2);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);


        boton2=new JButton("Mostrar");
        boton2.setMnemonic('D');
        boton2.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
        add(boton3);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);


        boton2=new JButton("Limpiar");
        boton2.setMnemonic('D');
        boton2.setBounds(500,120,100,30);
        add(boton4);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);
}

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource()==boton1) {
             linea="";
             linea1=textfield1.getText();
             linea2=textfield2.getText();
             linea3=textfield3.getText();
             linea4=textfield4.getText();
             linea5=textfield5.getText();
             id=Integer.parseInt(linea1);

try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

} catch(ClassNotFoundException e1) {

        System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
                                   }
if(id>0) {

try{

String password ="";

String dbName= "curso1.mdb";


String bd = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\" + dbName + ";PWD=" + password;

Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:;DRIVER=Microsoft Acces Driver (*.mdb,*.accdb);DBQ=" +bd);

Statement estatuto= conexion.createStatement();

aux1=Integer.parseInt(linea1);
aux3=Integer.parseInt(linea3);
aux4=Integer.parseInt(linea4);
aux5=Integer.parseInt(linea5);

String q="insert into lista (MATRICULA,NOMBRE,EX1,EX2,EX3)values("+aux1 +", '"+linea2+"',"+aux3+","+aux4+","+aux5+")";

estatuto.executeUpdate(q);
estatuto.close();
conexion.close();

}catch(SQLException e1){

texto.append(e1.getMessage());
}
}
else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La matricula es incorrecta, debe ser numerica");
}
tabla1();
limpiar();
}

if (e.getSource()==boton2) {

System.exit(0);
    }
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

based1 formulario1=new based1();
formulario1.setBounds(1,50,850,450);
formulario1.setVisible(true);
formulario1.setTitle("Formulario de ingreso de Datos Java+Acces");
   }

}
```

Comment: off topic a tu pregunta. En el título colocas *ERROR AL COMPILAR* pero lo que tú tienes es un error en tiempo de ejecución. Si tuvieses un error para compilar el código, tu programa no podría ni siquiera ejecutarse. Por favor considera esto al momento de redactar tus preguntas (quizás tu mal profesor de la otra ocasión no les corrige esto, qué mal por él).

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque el error se debe a un simple fallo tipográfico y es poco probable que sea de ayuda a otros usuarios en el futuro.

Comment: opino lo mismo a pesar de que alla sido yo quien iniciara el hilo mas sin embargo debo agradecer la atencion del Sr Luiggi Mendoza por resolver mi duda, se lo agradezco de gran corazon y esta sentencia gracias a usted podre  ya saber a que hace mencion de ahora en adelante y el titulo lo modificare ahora mismo

Comment: @Alvaro un error de tipeo lo asocio como falta de punto y coma o que se abre un bloque de código y no se cierra o cosas similares. El problema expuesto aca es sobre un NPE y que netamente se debe a que se usa una variable que tiene valor nulo (problema de fondo) y sobre ello se revisa que puede suceder

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza El problema ha sido por hacer un copia-pega y olvidarse de actualizar los nombres de las variables. Sí, es un NPE; pero está causado por un fallo tipográfico y encaja en la descripción de preguntas que no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías pertinentes (punto 2 en [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic))

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro lo conozco muy bien, pero si solo hubiesen dado como scope a revisar esas 4 líneas de codigo, pues no sabriamos si realmente hubiese sido ese problema tipografico.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Quizás yo estoy siendo un poco estricto en mi definición de fallo tipográfico, pero no estoy de acuerdo con ese último comentario. Si OP hubiera compartido esas 4 líneas de código sí se podría haber averiguado el problema. El primer comentario en la pregunta: "_hey, ¿por qué añades boton3 cuando creas boton2_"... y problema resuelto ¡sin ni siquiera saber que es un NPE!

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro mi primer comentario hubiese sido *asegurate de que boton3 este inicializado, al parecer trabajas todo con boton2 pero utilizas boton3* como algo de curiosidad. En fin, que los demas miembros de la comunidad emitan su opinion al respecto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es cuestión de leer el stacktrace. Revisemos:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Esta línea indica el hilo donde ocurrióel problema y la excepción o el error. En este caso, el tema de hilo no es muy relevante, así que enfoquémonos en el error: [`java.lang.NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). Este error sucede cuando estás utilizando una variable con valor `null` y ejecutas una operación sobre ella. Por ejemplo:

```
String nombre = null;
System.out.println("Hola " + nombre.trim());
```

El código de arriba lanzará esta excepción porque la variable `nombre` posee valor `null`. La solución es asegurarnos que no se utilice `null` al momento de la ejecución de esa línea de código. He aquí una forma de resolverlo, que es asignando un valor a la variable:

```
String nombre = " Karen :D ";
System.out.println("Hola " + nombre.trim()); //imprime: Hola Karen :D
```

Ahora, la segunda parte del stacktrace es un conjunto de llamadas a métodos apiladas que ejecuta el programa para su funcionamiento. En este caso, te indica en qué parte del código surgió el error:

> at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1041)
>   at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:959)
>   at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:545)
>   at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:365)
>   at based1.(based1.java:143)
>   at based1.main(based1.java:218)

Por lo visto, el problema sucedió en la clase `java.awt.Container`, en el método `addImpl`, y según la compilación actual de esta clase, en la línea 1041 de su archivo .java correspondiente. Puesto que `java.awt.Container` es una clase del JDK, no tiene mucho caso revisar lo que sucedió allí porque no es algo que podamos corregir (al menos no para este caso). Para ello, se debe inspeccionar más sobre la pila de las llamadas a métodos para encontrar alguna línea sobre la que nosotros trabajemos. Para este caso, la línea ganadora es:

> at based1.(based1.java:143)

¿Por qué esta es la línea que debemos revisar? Porque **esta línea de código pertenece a la clase que estamos desarrollando** y por ende nosotros **tenemos control** sobre lo que hay allí.

Revisando la línea 143 de tu archivo based1.java (que por cierto colocaste todo el archivo, facilitando su detección), se encuentra:

```
boton2=new JButton("Mostrar");
boton2.setMnemonic('D');
boton2.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
add(boton3); //<-- esta es la línea 143
boton2.addActionListener(this);
```

Al revisar el código, la variable `boton3` nunca fue inicializada, por lo que he allí el error.

¿Qué debe hacerse? A mí me da la impresión de que te equivocaste al declarar la variable en las líneas anteriores, en base a un fragmento mayor del código:

```
//líneas anteriores, acá veo que inicializas y utilizas boton2
boton2=new JButton("Salir");
boton2.setMnemonic('S');
boton2.setBounds(220,120,100,30);
add(boton2);
boton2.addActionListener(this);


//acá parece que copiaste/pegaste/trataste de adaptar el código anterior
//y se te olvidó utilizar boton3 en lugar de boton2
boton2=new JButton("Mostrar");
boton2.setMnemonic('D');
boton2.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
add(boton3);
boton2.addActionListener(this);
```

Así que es tema de reemplazar la variable utilizada:

```
boton3=new JButton("Mostrar");
boton3.setMnemonic('D');
boton3.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
add(boton3);
boton3.addActionListener(this);
```

Al parecer tienes una situación similar con `boton4` luego del problema con `boton3`, pero estoy seguro que con esta explicación podrás resolverlo.

Comment: Una explicación mucho más detallada que la mía

Comment: Quiero agradecerte por tu tiempo, enrealidad me ayudaste muchisimo aunque fuera una bobada mi error, gracias luiggi :DDDD <3

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza me corre el programa pero tengo un pequeño problema ahora y es que no guarda en mi BD la info  el programa aun arreglado los problemas que me mencionaste :'( 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/tiprhrkq51cv077/based1.rar

Comment: Hola @karen, de acuerdo a como funciona este sitio, si tienes un nuevo problema y sobretodo si es una situación diferente a la cubierta por esta pregunta entonces debería atenderse en otra pregunta. Con gusto revisare tu nueva pregunta cuando vuelva a entrar al sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Una excepción `NullPointerException` significa que alguna de las variables que estás usando es `null` pero estás intentando hacer una operación con ella.

Si miras el stack del error verás  que ocurre en la línea 143, que es `add(boton3)` dentro de esta parte:

```
boton2=new JButton("Mostrar");
boton2.setMnemonic('D');
boton2.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
add(boton3);
boton2.addActionListener(this);
```

El problema es que estás inicializando la variable `boton2` pero luego intentas añadir `boton3`. Cambia el código a:

```
boton3=new JButton("Mostrar");
boton3.setMnemonic('D');
boton3.setBounds(350,120,100,30);
add(boton3);
boton3.addActionListener(this);
```

Y lo mismo ocurre con la variable `boton4`